# Obtaining one taylor series from another taylor series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I computed the taylor series for

$$
\frac{2}{(3+x)}
$$

which is

$$
(-1)^n \times \frac{2}{(3^n+1)} \times x^n
$$

Now I need to compute the infinite series for

$$ 
2 \ln(3+x)
$$
using what I found for the taylor series in the first part.I'm really not seeing the linke here??Please help

Comment: Would you mind reformatting your math text a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int_a^x \frac{2}{3+t}dt=2\ln(x+3)-2\ln(3+a)$$
So you integrate the series that you get for first part.